# Break Point in Maven exec without Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, maven

Is there a way (not using Eclipse) to create a breakpoint in my Java Execution?
I am using Maven with the following command:
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="mypath.App"

I need to pause the Java application to print out my MySQL database tables to show the creation of an object, then hit play again to show the object being deleted.

The only method I have found for creating the break point is to open the project with Eclipse. I am trying to avoid using Eclipse if possible.

Comment: You know the `mvnDebug` command?

Comment: Breakpoints is something you usually set in IDEs like Eclipse. Can you explain why you want to avoid Eclipse/IntelliJ/Netbeans?

Comment: It is for a homework assignment, and I am not familiar with Eclipse. Eclipse is nice, but it has lots of added options that I don't fully understand. Maven is simple, as I only have to run two commands to test my application. No real technical limitation